# Vuejs DOM Not Updating

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

Ive got a simple edit screen set up here, and I don't know why its not hiding the form when I click save or cancel.

Form is being showing with a simple directive selected.name == p.name in a loop.  When I unset the selected object, its not updating the DOM.

The Form contents are saving to the array, as you can see if you make some changes, click save, and then click a new row.  But the form wont hide on cancel or on save.

Hopefully its something simple that I am overlooking.

Thanks

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    selected: {
     name:'',
     price: 0
    },
    products: [
      {name: 'Hamburger', price: 3.00},
      {name: 'Taco', price: 1.00},
      {name: 'Soda', price: 1.40},
      {name: 'French Fries', price: 2.00}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
      save: function(index){
          this.products[index] = this.selected;
          this.selected = {
              name:'',
              price: 0
       };
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="p, i in products" @click="selected = p">
      <span v-show="!selected || selected.name !== p.name">
        {{ p.name }}: ${{ p.price }}
      </span>
      <span v-show="selected && selected.name == p.name">
        <input type="text" v-model.lazy="selected.name" />
        <input type="text" v-model.lazy="selected.price" />
        <button @click="save(i)">Save</button>
        <button @click="selected = {}">Cancel</button>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `li` is always running its click event handler even when you click on a button so `selected` will always be reassigned to the current product.

To fix it, do **one** of the fllowing:

- Replace `@click` with `@click.stop` on each of the buttons to prevent the event from propagating up to the `li`.
- remove the `@click="selected = p"` from the `li` and add it to the first `span`. This way the handler will only be run when the form is not present.

Comment: Thank you! You are my hero.